# Can Anyone tell me why my script is disabling the s key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason whenever I run the script and it picks up the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> combo it seems to disable the <kbd>S</kbd> key until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> again...

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

```
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
    var isCtrl = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(!args) args=[]; // IE barks when args is null

        if(e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = true;
        if(e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && isCtrl) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
            return false;
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = false;
    });        
};

$.ctrl('S', function() { });
```

Comment: Passing _callback_ of `function() {console.log('s')}` makes the code work as expected in _Chrome_ for `Ctrl` + `S`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `isCtrl` var needed? I think this is enough:

```
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(!args) args=[]; // IE barks when args is null
        if(e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && e.ctrlKey) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
            return false;
        }
    });        
};

$.ctrl('S', function() {
    console.log("Pressed ctrl S")
});
```

Works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/X9SVC/1/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Mate Seems your snippet did the trick and didnt affect the other key functions... Thanks a Million

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the callback for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is never triggered. You can try clearing `isCtrl` after you call the function:

```
if(e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && isCtrl) {
    callback.apply(this, args);
    isCtrl = false;
    return false;
}
```